# Work database with visual interface

Tags: mac, database

I need a app that can help me work on a database with visual aid, I don't need it to be in a specific language, is only that I can see the workflow to better understand all the links between tables

Comment: How does a database have a workflow  could you expand on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few tools that can visually display database schemas. If you're using MySQL, you can use [MySQLWorkbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). Commercially, there is the [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/whatisnavicat) line of products. I haven't used them though. They are available on the Mac app store.

Looking just now, I see Wikipedia has a [page on data modeling tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_modeling_tools).